# Flux subscribeOn(elastic(), true) with flatMap not executing on different threads

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

**want to execute elements in the flux in asynchronously on different threads. 
but its not executing them on different threads. am i missing something?**

*below is the code.*

```
public Mono<Map<Object, Object>> execute(List<Empolyee> empolyeeList) {


        return Flux.fromIterable(empolyeeList).subscribeOn(elastic(), true).flatMap(empolyee -> {           

            return empolyeeService.getDepts(empolyee).flatMap(result -> {

             // ---
             // ---
             // ---

                return Mono.just(result);
            });

        }).collectMap(result -> result.getName().trim(), result -> fieldResult.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Please read about threads and schedulers https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers, Schedulers.elastic() does not guarantee execution on different threads, try for test purposes Schedulers.newSingle()

Answer (score 1):

taken from the documentation

> **subscribeOn applies to the subscription process**, when that backward
>   chain is constructed. As a consequence, no matter where you place the
>   subscribeOn in the chain, it always affects the context of the source
>   emission.

It does not work as you think. It applies to when someone subscribes. Their entire request will be placed on it's own tread. So there is an absolute guarantee that no two requests will end up on the same thread.

[The subscribeOn method](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_the_subscribeon_method)

Comment: thanks for quick reply @Thomas. i figured it out and its working as expected  posted my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58846432/8402445

Answer (score 0):

Made the flux as **parallel flux** and used **runOn(elastic())**. its working as expected

```
//Making flux as parallel flux, we can also use ParallelFlux instead of below
Flux.fromIterable(empolyeeList).parallel()

//running on elastic scheduler
.runOn(elastic()).flatMap(empolyee -> {

}
```